# Python script produces empty .csv file as output when it is supposed to produce True or False for 100,000 lines

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a python script that is supposed to take a directory full of .txt files and determine if each .txt file return positive or negative for matching certain text statements inside the file itself like "known infection source". However, my script runs for about 15 seconds and then says it is finished. However, the output.csv file the script creates is empty. The .csv file should contain true and false for roughly 100,000 .txt file Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Code**

```
import os
import json
import csv

path="C:/Users/bwerner/Documents/output/"


def vt_result_check(path):
    vt_result = False
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        with open(path + filename, 'r') as vt_result_file:
            vt_data = json.load(vt_result_file)

        # Look for any positive detected referrer samples
        # Look for any positive detected communicating samples
        # Look for any positive detected downloaded samples
        # Look for any positive detected URLs
        sample_types = ('detected_referrer_samples', 'detected_communicating_samples',
                        'detected_downloaded_samples', 'detected_urls')
        vt_result |= any(sample['positives'] > 0 for sample_type in sample_types
                                                 for sample in vt_data.get(sample_type, []))

        # Look for a Dr. Web category of known infection source
        vt_result |= vt_data.get('Dr.Web category') == "known infection source"

        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of elevated exposure
        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of phishing and other frauds
        # Look for a Forecepoint ThreatSeeker category of suspicious content
        threats = ("elevated exposure", "phishing and other frauds", "suspicious content")
        vt_result |= vt_data.get('Forcepoint ThreatSeeker category') in threats

        vt_result = int(vt_result)

        return vt_result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(vt_result_check(path)):
        f = csv.writer(open("output.csv", "wb+"))
        print(vt_result_check(path))
        f.writerow(vt_result_check(path))
```

Comment: You are opening a new file (with the same name) for each `i` in `__main__` block.

Comment: Your `vt_result_check` function returns exactly one integer.

Comment: @zvone Thank you for your comment! Do I not want to open a new file for each i?

Comment: @bedford How many files are you trying to create?

Comment: The answer is almost certainly no, you want one file of results.  Your goals may vary.  Also notice that what @KlausD. is saying is that `return vt_result`, at least, is indented within the `for filename in ...` which means it only reads one file then returns.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you for your comment! How do I get my function to return more than 1 integer?

Comment: Create a list before and `.append(vt_result)` to it at the end of the `for` block.

Comment: @zvone Thank you again for your comment! I'm trying to create 1 csv file with about 100,000 rows. I want to create 1 row for each .txt file I read in from the output directory.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you for your comment! I created an empty list in the beginning of the for block by doing L = [ ] and I appended it at the end of the for block by doing L.append(vt_result). Is there anything else I should do?